# How to remove Nvidia HDMI audio output in PulseAudio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

At each reboot, PulseAudio sets a sink (in my case, "HDMI Audio Output") as the default.

So, at each reboot, I don't hear any sound, and need to reconfigure the default sink each time to "Analog Output".

How do I remove/disable a specific sink such as HDMI, or set a default sink that overrides the existing sink?

Comment: Even if someone answers with a workaround please file a bug report for your issue as described at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs. Thanks

Comment: This is the second ranked question on Google for 'pulseaudio disable sink' and seems to be entirely within scope of using and administering official flavors of Ubuntu and doesn't fall into any of the avoided scope areas. Please reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. Delete User Settings

Another approach prior to editing the *default.pa* would be to rename the hidden directory `~/.pulseaudio` to something like `~/.pulseaudio.000` in your /home directory. This is where your user defined setup is stored. If deleted or renamed it will immediately be recreated from the */etc/pulse/default.pa* settings.

### 2. Edit Defaults

Only if this has no effect for your system then maybe udev loads the HDMI interface as default sink.  Then one approach could be as already mentioned by [HagenaarsDotNu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15497/how-to-remove-nvidia-hdmi-audio-output-in-pulseaudio/15553#15553) to edit the default.pa. **Mind to make a backup of the current default.pa.** Look for this section which is pretty self-explaining (mind that hal-detect will not work in Ubuntu >10.04).

```
### Load audio drivers statically (it's probably better to not load
### these drivers manually, but instead use module-hal-detect --
### see below -- for doing this automatically)
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-pipe-sink
#
### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
### Alternatively use the static hardware detection module (for systems that
### lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif
```

### 3. The Elegant Way

Another more elegant way to get audio working is to enable "Simultaneous Output" from **paprefs** as depicted here:

[image: paprefs]

This enables audio output on both, the internal audio, and the HDMI-Interface. Make this virtual output device your default and you have all options at your hands.

Comment: "Simultaneous Output" tend to be cpu intensive

Comment: "Simultaneous Output" also can potentially make audio quality terrible on at least one of the outputs. By terrible I mean it's really bad, arguably worse than no sound at all.

Comment: For people with zero experience with pulseaudio, the section is NOT self-explaining. What do I actually change, to disable audio-via-HDMI?

Comment: The last step of method 2 ends with "Look for this section which is pretty self-explaining". How does looking at that section have any impact on the system?

Answer (score 17):

Just set the soundcard's profile to "off", for example:

```
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.usb-Generic_ThinkPad_Dock_USB_Audio-00 off
```

`pavucontrol` can do this is well in its "Configuration" tab:

[image]

An alternative is to completely disable any auto connect functionality in pulseaudio, however I like this functionality in the case of my bluetooth headset.
With the above solution you can disable soundcards in a fine-grained manner.

Comment: What if your audio device doesn't _have_ a profile? My on-board HDMI and analog sound don't have one.

Comment: Never encountered that, can you show a screenshot of the screen used in the answer?

Comment: This would be a nice solution if it was remembered. I'm setting the profile on my HDMI Output and it just keeps resetting itself :( Extremely annoying. Kubuntu 21.04

Comment: @piit79 it is definitely remembered in my case.

Answer (score 10):

in 18.10 i was able to fix it

file */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf*
add

```
blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi
```

Answer (score 4):

I found [this suggestion on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/346753/comments/3)

which states you should edit the pulseaudio settings

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

and replace `#set-default-sink output` with: `set-default-sink {name of your device}`

Name of the device can be found by looking at `pactl list` output in the Card sections `name` field.

I checked and the approach should still be valid in 10.10

Comment: How do you know exactly which device name to use?

Answer (score 1):

**found a better option**

using systemd as described below worked on startup but not when plugging devices in to an already running system.

To ignore audio when hot-plugging *and* on boot, udev rules are the better option.

Adapted from [Tell PulseAudio to ignore a USB device using udev](https://jamielinux.com/blog/tell-pulseaudio-to-ignore-a-usb-device-using-udev/):

1. use `lsusb` to identify the vendor/product id of the device you want to ignore

   ```
   $ lsusb
   Bus 006 Device 003: ID 17e9:4307 DisplayLink LAPDOCK
   # <other devices I don't care about>
   ```

   the `ID` part gives us the magic numbers
2. create a udev rules file, e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-ignore-audio-cards.rules` that sets an environment variable for pulse audio.

   For me this looked like:

   ```
   ATTRS{idVendor}=="17e9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4307", ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"
   ```

   I chose the `80-` prefix for the filename arbitrarily. If you any pulseaudio related rules, make sure your new file starts with a lower number
3. reboot to ensure it takes effect

With the udev rule in place, pulseaudio ignores the device completely.

---

*previous answer:*

Ran into the same problem, and the given answers didn't work for me across restarts. I think my issue was delayed detection of cards; when pulseaudio started up it didn't see all the cards, and some combination of [`module-switch-on-connect`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-switch-on-connect) and [`module-switch-on-port-available`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-switch-on-port-available) was always resetting my choices.

I solved this by making a [systemd user unit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User) to run `pactl set_card_profile "$MY_CARD_NAME" off` when I logged in.

1. find the name of the card you don't want; hopefully the name should be enough to tell which one:

   ```
   $ pactl list cards | grep -E '(Card|Name:)'
   Card #0
       Name: alsa_card.usb-DisplayLink_LAPDOCK_U3D2338486250-02
   Card #1
       Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
   Card #2
       Name: alsa_card.usb-Plantronics_Plantronics_Blackwire_5220_Series_2961D11C621649939CED8BF57E910BA5-00
   Card #3
       Name: alsa_card.usb-HD_Web_Camera_HD_Web_Camera_Ucamera001-02
   Card #4
       Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
   ```

   For me, it was the "LAPDOCK" that kept stealing my audio.
2. create the systemd unit, to call `pactl` and disable the card:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user
   $ nano ~/.config/systemd/user/disable-cards.service
   ```

   Add these contents, changing the `ExecStart` line to refer to the card you want to drop:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Disable card

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   Restart=on-failure
   ExecStart=pactl set-card-profile "alsa_card.usb-DisplayLink_LAPDOCK_U3D2338486250-02" off

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```
3. enable the service: `systemctl --user enable disable-cards`

Now when you restart systemd will keep trying to disconnect that card until it succeeds. There's probably better `systemd` config to get this running after the monitor is plugged in; each device shows up as a "unit" (e.g. in the output of `systemctl --user`) so this could be improved to work as you plug/unplug things.

The other alternative is to change your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to use `module-switch-on-connect blacklist="REGEX_MATCHING_THE_CARD_NAME"`, but that didn't work for me; there's no way to customize `module-switch-on-port-available`, and I think that's what was selecting it for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround please disable that feature by editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and comment out (with `#`) or remove:

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

and reboot the system.