# How to disable pulseaudio automatic device switch?

Tags: pulseaudio

My speakers are plugged via optical output. Each time my screen wake up from sleep, pusleaudio automatically switch to HDMI audio where nothing is plugged.

How can I prevent that ?

Comment: The Real Question is "why is this the default behaviour?"
How is it good?, that everytime you want to listen to something you have to change the configuration.
Just pure bad dev.
Thank you for asking this question, because the answer was spot on.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let me know if this doesn't work for you and I'll delete my answer. I don't have your speaker system but this should work.

## Disable automatic device switching

When signal is lost to during sleep, Pulse Audio is automatically configured to activate the default source (your HDMI). Upon resume the sound device is still on HDMI. To override this setting, tell Pulse Audio to never switch sound devices automatically:

- edit the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- find the line `load-module module-switch-on-port-available`
- insert a `#` at the beginning of the line to disable automatic port switching
- save file and exit editor
- type `pulseaudio -k` to reload configuration

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Just for the note I restarted pulse without rebooting using 'pulseaudio -k' .

Comment: @VincentTschanz Thank you for your comment. I've updated the answer with it.

Comment: This is problematic since it disable automatic speaker / headphone toggling :/

Comment: @PetterSundlöf Yes you would have to switch output devices manually. It's the lesser of two evils.

Comment: I wonder if you could have a look at [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636598/how-to-control-pulseaudio-automatic-device-switching-priority) of mine, on Unix.SX.

Comment: @einpoklum Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/15497/how-to-remove-nvidia-hdmi-audio-output-in-pulseaudio

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Unfortunately, not really...

Comment: Great answer, so simple for such an annoying problem. LifeSaver!

Comment: This also fixed my issue where glava switches to my microphone instead of the monitor of my main output when I plug the mic in.

Answer (score 6):

WinEunuuchs2Unix's post is correct, but I had to adjust `module-switch-on-connect` instead of `module-switch-on-port-available`. Here's an easy one-liner:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^load-module module-switch-on-connect$/# load-module module-switch-on-connect/g' /etc/pulse/default.pa && pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: By keeping `switch-on-port-available` and  disabling `swith-on-connect` I finally managed what I want: automatic switching between speakers/headphones, but ignoring my docking station. Thank you! This has been bugging me for about a year now.

Comment: @Sebastiaan What's the exact difference between `on-port-available` and `on-connect`?

Comment: `on-connect` is the event that a new  device is connected which has an audio port, such as a usb dock. `on-port-available` is the event that a port becomes usable, for example when you insert a mini jack.

Answer (score 0):

By the way just related I had the same problem. There seem to be a bug report up on Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1847570

Comment: That bug report is for Ubuntu 19.10 released October 2019. This question is from August 2018.