# Pause music when bluetooth connection drops

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I play music through my wireless bluetooth earphones at my desk through my ubuntu laptop (regolith-linux).

However when I leave my desk to go help someone with a Docker issue, I usually have my earphones round my neck which means at some point (after a surprising distance) the connection to my laptop drops.

The issue being, if my music has not paused it will switch to the onboard speakers and start playing my heavy metal very loudly in the office.

Does anyone know how I can get my music to pause when the sound device has dropped connection?

Or it doesn't even need to pause my music per se - just stop it from switching to my Built-in speakers automatically!

Comment: I wrote an answer to that some time ago but am currently on my phone. Basically you tell pulse audio not to automatically switch output sources when a connection is dripped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct would be to pause the music on the earbuds as the range distorts the sound. But as you say this doesn't work. The second option would be to tell Pulse Audio not to switch sound to the speakers when earbuds are out of range.

Try this:

## Disable automatic device switching

- edit the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- find the line `load-module module-switch-on-port-available`
- insert a `#` at the beginning of the line to disable automatic port switching
- save file and exit editor
- type `pulseaudio -k` to reload configuration

Source: [How to disable pulseaudio automatic device switch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061414/how-to-disable-pulseaudio-automatic-device-switch/1061578#1061578)