# How to prevent audio from playing through speakers after disconnecting from bluetooth device on pipewire?

Tags: sound, pipewire

I'm using pipewire on arch and struggle with the fact that my speakers will blast music after I walk out of range with my bluetooth headset.

[I have the exact same problem as this guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178688/pause-music-when-bluetooth-connection-drops), and the answer there says to disable automatic device switching. Does anyone know if that is possible with pipewire? Or if there is an alternative method to pause audio?

Comment: Also wondering this now that I got rid of pulseaudio due to conflicts with other stuff