# Pulseaudio auto-switches devices despite commenting out module-switch-on-port-available

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Whenever I plug in my microphone, my computer switches its source and sink to the microphone (the microphone has an aux output), but I don't want it to automatically switch either.

I tried to fix it by commenting out `load-module module-switch-on-port-available` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/1061578/712826, and it seemed to work for about a week, but now it automatically switches again.

I've tried commenting out `module-switch-on-connect` as well, with no change.

I've run `pulseaudio -k` and restarted after making any changes.

The relevant part of `/etc/pulse/default.pa` is here:

```
### Should be after module-*-restore but before module-*-detect
#load-module module-switch-on-port-available

### Use hot-plugged devices like Bluetooth or USB automatically (LP: #1702794)
#.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
#load-module module-switch-on-connect
#.endif
```

I've also confirmed that the modules are correctly not loaded:

```
$ pactl unload-module module-switch-on-port-available
Failed to unload module: Module module-switch-on-port-available not loaded
$ pactl unload-module module-switch-on-connect       
Failed to unload module: Module module-switch-on-connect not loaded
```

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-58-generic

PulseAudio version: 13.99.1