# How can i set the default audio output?

Tags: sound, hdmi, default

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 on a raspberry pi 4. It's connected to a Sony TV with an HDMI cable. When I boot the system, the audio is set to headphones. (There isn't a headphone connected) I have to set it to 'digital output built in speakers' manually every time.

How can I set the default audio output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable pulseaudio automatic device switch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061414/how-to-disable-pulseaudio-automatic-device-switch)

Comment: There was similar topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks for the replies and advice. I tried them both but they didn't work. The second one may have worked but in Ubuntu 21.04 there is no option to do that like the screen shot he posted

Comment: the link to the solution posted by @BohdanTkhir worked for me in Ubuntu 21.04 in RPi4.. Just follow the instructions..