# Disable HDMI audio on ubuntu studio 19.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.04

Ubuntu Studio 19.04, i've been trying to change the default audio output to the analog one. the computer is connected to a monitor with speakers and speakers on the analog output.
each restart the audio output changes back to the HDMI.
i've tried defining it with pavucontrol (the settings won't keep)
i've also tried setting the sink in the default.pa file to the correct sink, but still on restart it comes back to the hdmi.
even tried to make a startup script to switch between the sinks, but that also didn't work...

i've looked at these guides also just for reference.
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/pulseaudio-default-output-wont-stay/16452
https://rastating.github.io/setting-default-audio-device-in-ubuntu-18-04/

any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

This problem is happening to a lot of people including me in Ubuntu 19.10 due to a [bug 1847570 PulseAudio automatically switches to HDMI sound output on login](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1847570).

The only solution that worked for me was by Selmi in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15497/how-to-remove-nvidia-hdmi-audio-output-in-pulseaudio):

1. Open a terminal
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
3. Add `blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi` to the end of the file on its own line
4. Save the file (CTRL+O) and exit (CTRL+X) nano
5. Reboot.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, blacklisting `snd_hda_codec_hdmi` causes both `alsa` and `pulseaudio` to fail during startup.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the last part of the default.pa instructions is to delete the .tmp file before restarting - perhaps that's what you're missing? Also, another user had mentioned commenting out "load-module module-switch-on-connect" to prevent the system from automatically switching when you plug in the monitor.

I actually came across this question, because I want to do a similar thing, but in reverse - I want to disable my onboard sound. On Win7-10, you can 'disable' the output so it is never used. Useful, when I know I'll only ever need sound when I plug in my HDMI monitor with sound output. I can't seem to find any instructions on how to disable the specific output - only a lot of instructions on how to disable a sound event.